# Name Error despite having defined it earlier?

Tags: python, error-handling, syntax-error, cluster-analysis

```
def categorise_sourceIP(df):
    df_sIPf = pd.df.sourceIP.value_counts()
    df_sIPf['counts'] = np.array(df.sourceIP.value_counts())
    df_sIPf['sourceIP'] = df_sIPf.index
    df_sIPf.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True,drop=True)
    counts_cate = []
    for num in df_sIPf['counts']:
        if num in range(0,21):
            counts_cate.append('<20')
        elif num in range(21,201):
                counts_cate.append('21-200')
        elif num in range(201,401):
            counts_cate.append('201-400')
        elif num > 400:
            counts_cate.append('>400')
counts_cate=df_sIPf['categorised_count']
```

The error call back is the following

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-9622f76efabe> in <module>
     27         elif num > 400:
     28             counts_cate.append('>400')
---> 29 counts_cate=df_sIPf['categorised_count']

NameError: name 'df_sIPf' is not defined
```

How do I fix this? At a key stage in my problem set.
Essentially trying to build a relationship between clusters of two different variables in the dataframe so a similar piece of code will be written for the second set.

Comment: your assignment statement is outside your function definition

Answer (score 2):

You need to return `df_sIPf` from your function if you want it to be accessible outside that function:

```
def categorise_sourceIP(df):
    df_sIPf = pd.df.sourceIP.value_counts()
    df_sIPf['counts'] = np.array(df.sourceIP.value_counts())
    df_sIPf['sourceIP'] = df_sIPf.index
    df_sIPf.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True,drop=True)
    counts_cate = []
    for num in df_sIPf['counts']:
        if num in range(0,21):
            counts_cate.append('<20')
        elif num in range(21,201):
                counts_cate.append('21-200')
        elif num in range(201,401):
            counts_cate.append('201-400')
        elif num > 400:
            counts_cate.append('>400')
    return df_sIPf

counts_cate = categorise_sourceIP(df)['categorised_count']
```

Comment: return' outside function-how do I deal with this error?

Comment: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'df'-Further error that is coming!

Comment: re: `return outside function`, you have to put the `return` inside the function.

Comment: re `df`, your function takes a dataframe as its input, right?  You need to provide that.